# Why might a monotone increasing but nonlinear transformation of a utility function not represent the same preferences?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, preferences

According to a textbook, a monotone increasing but nonlinear transformation of a utility function might not represent the same preferences. Why is it so?

An example of such preference would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I am underthinking this, but the transformation has to be _strictly_ monotone increasing. I think it is simple to see why, as only the strictly monotone function would keep the ordering of any preference relation intact.

But you probably meant something else?

Comment: Thank you. I somehow thought that monotone increasing the same as strictly monotone increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason I could think of is regarding convexity of the function (and hence risk aversion). For example, $u(x) = x$ is risk neutral, but $v(x) = \ln(u(x)) = \ln(x)$ is risk averse.

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Utility_of_money).